# Apache PDFBox 2.0 - Text is not shown in created PDF file

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm using the following method to create a PDF file:

```
private void createPdf() throws IOException {
    PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    doc.addPage(new PDPage());

    PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);

    content.beginText();
    content.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA, 26);
    content.showText("Example Text");
    content.endText();

    content.close();

    doc.save("report.pdf");
    doc.close();
}
```

It creates a new file with a white page, but no text is shown. What's wrong?

I use Apache PDFBox 2.0.7.

Comment: Have you looked at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Vega, what @Tilman hints at is that you did not indicate any position for the text. Thus, it is drawn at (0,0) which in case of your code is in the lower left corner of the page.

Comment: I double-checked, but there is nothing on the page. Thanks for the hint. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this code

```
PDPage page = new PDPage();
doc.addPage(new PDPage());
```

to this

```
PDPage page = new PDPage();
doc.addPage(page);
```

You made the mistake to add a new page with nothing. The operations you did were done on another object.

Your text should now be visible at the bottom of the page. (y = 0 is bottom in PDF)